# Meaning of the participle "being bitten by insects"

Tags: meaning-in-context, participle-clauses

> I don't want to stay out here **being bitten by insects**

What does the above sentence (especially adverbial participle clause) mean?

Does it have a *continuous* meaning like,

1. After I am/was being bitten by insects, I don't want stay out here.
2. because I am being bitten by insects, I don't...
3. while/when I am being bitten by insects, I don't...

Comment: Read it as: "I don't want to stay out here [where I am] being bitten by insects."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does have a continuous meaning. If you are *being bitten* by insects you are being bitten repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

"I don't want to stay out here being bitten by insects".

We can use a present participle to replace "as, because or since + subject + verb" to express the cause or reason for an action. In the sentence,  being bitten has been used to mean "as I am bitten".

In other words, the sentence means "I don't want to stay out here as I am bitten by insects.  I think the meaning of the sentence is quite clear.  However, the sentences # 1 and 3 sound incorrect  to interpret the sense of the sentence in question.